# Errors in console when running anything in Flutter Web (Vs Code)

Tags: flutter, runtime-error, flutter-web

Edit: These messages only pop up in Visual Studio Code's Debug Console. The issue does not occur when running from the terminal. There might be some issue with the Flutter extension.

I'm getting error messages in my console whenever I run anything in Flutter Web and they appear again after every Hot Reload/Hot Restart, even with a freshly created project. Here they are:

```
Error handling 'checkPlatformOverride' custom request: _flutter.listViews: (-32601) Unknown method "_flutter.listViews".
Error handling 'checkBrightnessOverride' custom request: _flutter.listViews: (-32601) Unknown method "_flutter.listViews".
Error handling 'checkIsWidgetCreationTracked' custom request: _flutter.listViews: (-32601) Unknown method "_flutter.listViews".
Error handling 'serviceExtension' custom request: _flutter.listViews: (-32601) Unknown method "_flutter.listViews".
```

Any ideas what's causing this? The apps work fine but it takes up a lot of space in the console after a while.

Here is my `flutter doctor -v` output, for reference (switched to master a few minutes ago to see if that'd fix the issue):

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 2.3.0-1.0.pre.243, on macOS 11.3 20E232 darwin-arm, locale en-FR)
    • Flutter version 2.3.0-1.0.pre.243 at /Users/lemomar/dev/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 9cc8d78ec7 (34 minutes ago), 2021-05-07 05:57:27 -0700
    • Engine revision f57e986aa8
    • Dart version 2.14.0 (build 2.14.0-74.0.dev)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/lemomar/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.5, Build version 12E262
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.56.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.22.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.90
    ! Error: iPhone is not connected. Xcode will continue when iPhone is connected. (code -13)
```

Comment: the error occurrs when running in debug mode using visual studio code, also.  It does not occur when running flutter run -d chrome.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that the other day. Are you experiencing at as well?

Comment: I switch to windows 10 with visual studio code and flutter.  Running in debug does not throw these errors in this environment.  I created a new project after doing flutter upgrade and move my source code to the new project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been solved as of Friday June 4th 2021.